# Strange behaviour on Update query with C# and Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am facing a strange problem, When i try to run the below code to update a record in access db.

```
string updateQuery = "UPDATE Employee SET Employee_name = @name, Employee_desig = @designation, Employee_salary = @salary, Employee_phone = @phone, Employee_mobile = @mobile, Employee_email = @email, Employee_status = @status WHERE (((Employee_id)=@empId));";

dbCmd.CommandText = updateQuery;

dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", designation);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mobile);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", salary);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empId", employeeId);

dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`ExecuteNonQuery()` return 1. But when i check in db, inputs are updated in different columns.

[image: screenshot access db]

input values are

```
designation="Manager"
email="e"
mobile="2"
name="n"
phone="1"
salary=10.0
status="Active"
employeeId=3
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am using OleDbCommand.

Comment: Your update query and the order the Parameters were added don't match yet they match what actually being done.

Comment: Thanks. Question closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of ACE OLEDB the parameter names are ignored and the parameters must be defined in the same order that they appear in the SQL statement.